# Angular Controller Using ngClipboard - Error: Unknown provider

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to set an `ng-click` event inside of a controller so that when the user clicks a div the function is ran and compiles a string and adds it to the clipboard.

I'm getting the following error though:

```
angular.js:13550Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: ngClipboardProvider <- ngClipboard <- eventCtrl
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div><div ng-click="vm.copy()" class="button tiny">Copy</div></div>
</div>
```

**Angular Controller** (updated)

```
(function() {

    angular
        .module('monitorApp', ['ngClipboard'])
        .controller('eventCtrl', eventCtrl);

    eventCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'monitorData', 'ngClipboard'];
    function eventCtrl($scope, $routeParams, monitorData, ngClipboard) {
        var vm = this;

        vm.copy = function() {
            vm.copyjunk = "COPIED crap here!!";
            vm.copyjunk = ngClipboard.toClipboard;
        };
    }

})();
```

I have some other code in the controller that deals with a service I created, but for simplicity sake, I excluded it and only have the bare essentials for the ngClipboard.

I've also tried many different variations of injecting `ngClipboard` into the controller, but it doesn't seem to work. Thanks for any help!

(note: I have included `clipboard.min.js` and `ngclipboard.min.js` in my html)

**EDIT (SOLVED)**

*HTML*

```
<div ngclipboard data-clipboard-text="COPIED TEXT HERE!" class="button tiny">Copy Dial-in</div>
```

*Controller*

```
Left it alone, no "ngclipboard" stuff here
```

*app.js* (NEW! - primary angular file)

```
angular.module('monitorApp', ['ngRoute','ngclipboard']);
```

So putting the new addition of ['ngclipboard'] into the main file and not a controller allowed the app to work properly. Before, the app would load, no errors, but entire page would be blank. Special thanks to Shannon for the help.

Comment: How do you add the `ngClipboard` lib to your app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you include the source correctly like so into the bottom of body

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/zenorocha/clipboard.js/master/dist/clipboard.min.js"></script>
<script src="dist/ngclipboard.min.js"></script>
```

Looks like you've simply missed the module dependency.

`angular.module('monitorApp'), ['ngclipboard']);`

Not only that, but you've tried to use a provider called `ngClipboard` which does not exist in the source.

This ngclipboard module uses attribute directives only. **HTML**:

```
<!-- Target -->
<input id="foo" value="https://github.com/sachinchoolur/ngclipboard.git">

<!-- Trigger -->
<button class="btn" ngclipboard data-clipboard-target="#foo">
    <img src="assets/clippy.svg" alt="Copy to clipboard">
</button>
```

This will copy the content from the input when the button is pressed (targets the id).

In your case, if your `vm.copy()` method just returns a string, just do something like this:

```
<button class="btn" ngclipboard data-clipboard-text="{{vm.copy()}}">
    {{vm.copy()}}
</button>
```

Comment: I tried that actually, and my page loads completely blank. Any idea why?

Comment: None are displaying in the console :/

Comment: Are you defining your module elsewhere? we kind of need to see more examples your code. Are you sure you have got the case correct? It is case sensitive. Make sure you reference the working demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/TMGDUH5IG4GazpBvT2rQ?p=info

Comment: in the `ngclipboard.js` it has `var MODULE_NAME = 'ngclipboard';` so I'm declaring in my controller with lowercase "c", when a lot of examples use "C" (ie "ngClipboard"). Perhaps if I download the older ngController.js it will work

Comment: I've noticed this `.factory` thing, and I'm not working with factories or ever used it. Could that produce a problem?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the module you're using? There's a few called ngClipboard.

Comment: @Kenny, you are using a provider that does not exist that's your main issue!

Comment: Thanks for the help, Shannon. Is the only thing in my angular code the `angular
            .module('monitorApp', ['ngclipboard'])
            .controller('eventCtrl', eventCtrl);`?

Comment: Thanks, I got it! What I had to do was, in addition to what you suggested, I was adding `['ngclipboard']` to my controller, but I needed to add it to my app.js (main angular file, where I also have other `ng` junk. So in my main angular file I have `angular.module('monitorApp', ['ngRoute','ngclipboard']);`.

Answer (score 0):

The ngClipboard module is a directive only. Bringing it into my controller breaks my app as well. You just need to add the markup directly into your view:

---

```
<button class="btn" ngclipboard data-clipboard-text="Just because you can doesn't mean you should — clipboard.js">
    Copy to clipboard
</button>
```

---

```
<button class="btn" ngclipboard data-clipboard-text="{{vm.copyjunk}}">
    {{vm.copyjunk}}
</button>
```

Comment: Did you have to do anything inside your Angular app? Or simply add the `ngClipboard.js` into your html then add the directive?

Comment: Just like they suggest in the comments on the answer, you add the module via script/src and then tell your base app that you're going to use the directive by calling `angular.module('mon‌​itorApp', ['ngRoute','ngclipbo‌​ard']);`